# Text dynamic size - Animate CC HTML5canvas

Tags: text, dynamic, html5-canvas, animate-cc

I need to have a dynamic text field to control by code the size of the text and the text.

I create a dynamic text field on the Stage with the "notification" instance and the following code:

```
function Message () {
var text1 = new createjs.Text ("Message", "15px Arial", "# ff7700");
text.textBaseline = "alphabetic";
stage.addChild (text);
}
this.notification.text = text1;
```

What am I doing wrong? From already thank you very much

Comment: What exactly ain't working Rodrigo?

Comment: Welcome! `createjs` is not a thing, maybe you have defined it somewhere else ? If that is the case, please provide that class.

Answer (score 0):

half resolved

```
var text = new createjs.Text("Mensaje", "25px Times Bold", "#ff0000");
text.x = 150;
text.y = 150;
text.color = "#0000ff";
text.textAlign = "center";
text.textBaseline = "alphabetic";
stage.addChild(text);
```